# How to convert two dimensional array to three dimensional array based on specific key value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.

```
$majorEarning = array(
                    array(
                            'user_id' => 1,
                            'booking_id' => 2,
                            'price' => 30
                        ),
                    array(
                            'user_id' => 2,
                            'booking_id' => 1,
                            'price' => 60
                        ),
                    array(
                            'user_id' => 2,
                            'booking_id' => 6,
                            'price' => 10
                        ),
                    array(
                            'user_id' => 1,
                            'booking_id' => 4,
                            'price' => 50
                        )    
    );
```

I need to reorder and restructure it like this:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [booking_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 2
                            [price] => 30
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 4
                            [price] => 50
                        )    

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [booking_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 1
                            [price] => 60
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 6
                            [price] => 10
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

This is my coding:-

```
$formattedEarning = array();
foreach($majorEarning as $keyEarn => $row)
   {
       if(!empty($formattedEarning))
       {
           $return = myfunction($formattedEarning, 'user_id', $row['user_id']);
           if($return)
           {
               $earning = array();
                $earning['booking'] = $row['booking_id'];
                $earning['price']   = $row['price'];
                $formattedEarning[$return]['booking_data'][] = $earning;
           }
           else
           {
               $earning = array();
               $earningChild = array();
                $earning['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $earningChild['booking']         = $row['booking_id'];
                $earningChild['price']    = $row['price'];
                $earning['booking_data'][]  = $earningChild;
                $formattedEarning[] = $earning;
            }
       }
       else
       {
           $earning = array();
               $earningChild = array();
          $earning['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $earningChild['booking']         = $row['booking_id'];
                $earningChild['price']    = $row['price'];
                $earning['booking_data'][]  = $earningChild;
                $formattedEarning[] = $earning;

       }
    }



print_r($formattedEarning);

function myfunction($products, $field, $value)
{
   foreach($products as $key => $product)
   {
      if ( $product[$field] === $value )
         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}
```

But the array is coming like this:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [booking_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 2
                            [price] => 30
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [booking_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 1
                            [price] => 60
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 6
                            [price] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [booking_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [booking] => 4
                            [price] => 50
                       )
                )
        )
)
```

Don't know why, a new element with `user_id = 1` is getting appended. As `user_id = 1` is already exisiting, instead of another new element with `user_id = 1`, the booking details should get appended to the `booking_data` of the previous record.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the online Sandbox link:- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0feb80c20e2b7df30fdf05662cd7aea415b29464

Comment: You will need to use temporary (userid) keys then reindex later.  If I didn't have a family I would answer.  Is the input coming from a mysql resultset? Why do you actually need the new structure?

Comment: May be you should use the user_id as array key of the single arrays (instead of 0, 1, 2, ...) so you can simply sort in booking and price. May be check if key exists and if not create a new array with the user_id key.

Comment: If this is a mysql result set, are you using pdo?

Comment: What is the benefit to your project ny grouping? What is the next step? How is this data used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach` with `array_key_exists`

```
$r = [];
foreach($majorEarning as $v){
    array_key_exists($v['user_id'], $r)
    ?
    ($r[$v['user_id']]['booking_data'][] = 
    ['booking'=>$v['booking_id'],'price'=>$v['price']])
    :
    ($r[$v['user_id']] = ['user_id' => $v['user_id'], 'booking_data' => [['booking'=>$v['booking_id'], 'price'=>$v['price']]]]);
}
```

To re-arrange keys use `array_values($r)`

Working Demo : https://3v4l.org/bFKE4

Comment: Your array doesn't have the 0th index. You are setting the index based on the user_id. I don't need that.

Comment: use `array_values($r)` to re-arrange array keys, check this one https://3v4l.org/cGgo1

Answer (score 1):

You car iterate you array like this, check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a34c7aec8fa401991574fe808b911b5b751abc8)

```
$result = [];
foreach($majorEarning as $array){
    $user_id = $array["user_id"];
    $result[$user_id]["user_id"] = $user_id;
    $result[$user_id]["booking_data"][] = array(
        "booking" => $array["booking_id"],
        "price" => $array["price"]
    );
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'booking_id' => 2,
        'price' => 30
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'booking_id' => 1,
        'price' => 60
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'booking_id' => 6,
        'price' => 10
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'booking_id' => 4,
        'price' => 50
    ]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[$entry['user_id']]['user_id'] = $entry['user_id'];
    $output[$entry['user_id']]['booking_data'][] = [
        'booking' => $entry['booking_id'],
        'price' => $entry['price']
    ];
});
var_dump(array_values($output));
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["booking_data"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["booking"]=>
        int(2)
        ["price"]=>
        int(30)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["booking"]=>
        int(4)
        ["price"]=>
        int(50)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["booking_data"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["booking"]=>
        int(1)
        ["price"]=>
        int(60)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["booking"]=>
        int(6)
        ["price"]=>
        int(10)
      }
    }
  }
}
```